# pygame 'module' object not callable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, pygame

So I just started using python and pygame to start building a poker program, and I downloaded a bunch of images for the cards. I started making a test program for the images:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 675))   #Sets the screen to a 16:9 ratio display
pygame.display.set_caption('Poker Program')     #Used to set the window name as whatever's in the brackets
feltGreen = (0,200,0)                           #What is used for the color (r,g,b)(the higher the number, the lighter the colour)
screen.fill(feltGreen)
pygame.display.update()                         #Updates the screen

twoc = pygame.image("2_of_clubs.png")
twod = pygame.image("2_of_diamonds.png")
twoh = pygame.image("2_of_hearts.png")
twos = pygame.image("2_of_spades.png")
threec = pygame.image("3_of_clubs.png")
threed = pygame.image("3_of_diamonds.png")
threeh = pygame.image("3_of_hearts.png")
threes = pygame.image("3_of_spades.png")
```

For the first while, it works perfectly. But then I get this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Z & Z Azam/Desktop/New folder (2)/Python Stuff/PycharmProjects/ProjectGambler/Graphics-Cards.py", line 15, in <module>
    twoc = pygame.image("2_of_clubs.png")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've tried everything, but it still says that. Is there anything I can do to make it work?

PS The folder where I store the cards is in the scripts folder of Python35.

Update: I've replaced all the pygame.image with pygame.image.load, but now I get this instead:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Z & Z Azam/Desktop/New folder (2)/Python Stuff/PycharmProjects/ProjectGambler/Graphics-Cards.py", line 15, in <module>
    twoc = pygame.image.load("2_of_clubs.png")           #Lines 15-66 bring all the cards into the program
pygame.error: Couldn't open 2_of_clubs.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.image` is not a function so is not callable. You probably want to use `pygame.image.load()` instead.

Source: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html

Edit:

You're probably getting the new error because python can't find the file. You should use the absolute path of the file. E.g. `pygame.image.load('C:\\pictures\\2_of_clubs.png')`.

Ps. you don't need to list all those modules in your question. It's making the question unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `pygame.image` is not actually a function - it's a module (hence the text of the error). To load an image, use the function `pygame.image.load(filename)`.